# how to default PHP generated date range to the current week

Tags: php, select, for-loop

I have the below syntax which populates a drop down box with week periods. it ranges from 3 months ago to 1 year ahead.

```
<select id="period" name="period" onchange="updateperioddiv();"  class="tekwani-input-select"> 

        <?php
          for($i = 0; $i <= 445; $i ++){

            $startdate = strtotime("today + $i day - 90 day");
            $enddate = strtotime("today + " . ($i + 6) . " day - 90 day ");

            if(date('D', $startdate) == 'Mon'){

                echo '<option'.' value="'. date('Y-m-d', $startdate) . ' ">' .date('d M y', $startdate) . " to " . date('d M y', $enddate) . "</option>";
            }
          }
        ?> 
   </select>
```

so this defaults to the 3 months ago, how can I get it to have the default selected as the current week?

php fiddel [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0ba-cqy)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime() returns Unix timestamps, which are represented as numbers, you can therefore do simple logical compares on the values to determine if today is inside a particular week.

```
// Get unix time of today
$today = strtotime("today");

for($i = 0; $i <= 445; $i ++){

    $startdate = strtotime("today + $i day - 90 day");
    $enddate = strtotime("today + " . ($i + 6) . " day - 90 day "); 

    if(date('D', $startdate) == 'Mon'){

        echo '<option ';
        // check to see if today is inside this week
        if( $startdate < $today && $enddate > $today ){
            echo ' selected="selected"';
        }

        echo ' value="'. date('Y-m-d', $startdate) . ' ">' .date('d M y', $startdate) . " to " . date('d M y', $enddate) . "</option>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Will, so logical. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this-

```
<select id="period" name="period" onchange="updateperioddiv();"  class="tekwani-input-select"> 

        <?php
            echo "week".date("Y",$startdate);
          for($i = 0; $i <= 445; $i ++){

            $startdate = strtotime("today + $i day - 90 day");
            $enddate = strtotime("today + " . ($i + 6) . " day - 90 day ");

            if(date('D', $startdate) == 'Mon'){
                $selected = "";
                if(date('W', $startdate) == date('W'))
                   $selected = "selected";
                echo '<option'.' value="'. date('Y-m-d', $startdate) . ' " $selected>' .date('d M y', $startdate) . " to " . date('d M y', $enddate) . "</option>";
            }
          }
        ?> 
   </select>
```